# $\int_{|x-y|\leq |x|} |x|^{-s} |x-y|^{s-d} dy \leq C ?$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $0<s<d,$ and $x,y\in \mathbb R^d.$

Assume that $|x-y|\leq \min \{|x|, |y|\}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^d.$

> My Question:
>   Can we find some  constant $C$ such that
>   $$\int_{|x-y|\leq |x|} |x|^{-s} |x-y|^{s-d} dy \leq C ?$$

My thought: Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C$ (be nice).  We have formula (using polar coordinates),
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(|x|) dx= C_1 \int_0^{\infty} f(|x|) |x|^{d-1} d(|x|).$$Maybe I have to invoke this formula, but I am bit confused as  integration of the above question is over $\{y\in \mathbb R^d: |x-y|\leq |x| \}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral $I$ runs over the ball $B_{|x|}(x)$ (centered at $x$ with radius $|x|$), hence with a change of variables $z = y-x$:
$$
I = |x|^{-s} \int_{B_{|x|}(x)} |y-x|^{s-d} dy =
|x|^{-s} \int_{B_{|x|}(0)} |z|^{s-d} dz
= |x|^{-s} C_1 \int_0^{|x|} \rho^{s-d} \rho^{d-1} d\rho = C_1.
$$

Comment: @R, Thanks.  If we do change of variable, then we have $B_{|x|}(x)= x+ B_{|x|}(0),$ not just $B_{|x|}(0)$? Correct? Does not this create trouble?

Comment: In the first integral you have $y \in B_{|x|}(x) = x + B_{|x|}(0)$. In the second integral, with the change of variable $z := y-x$, you have $z\in B_{|x|}(0)$.